# Why did Alexander the Great spare Porus's life?

Tags: india, alexander-the-great

Between Persia & India, Alexander had become more ruthless, massacring cities even when they didn't resist.

He always executed any who resisted before [Porus/Purushottama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Porus).

Why was Porus/Purushottama allowed to live?

Comment: Well, I guess we can't ask Alexander the Great. In fact, even if we could ask him how could we trust him to tell us the truth? I mean what if Alexander said, "I spared Porus because of X, Y and Z", but what if the real reason was some other reasons, P and Q. How would we know if Alexander was lying to us or not?

Comment: Who was Porus?  Can you show preliminary research?

Answer (score 0):

Defeating Parvateshwar (Porus) had been a very difficult task. Moreover Sage Dandyayan had told him that it is impossible to win over this country. When asked, Maharaj Parvateshwar told him to behave with him as a king. So he left him.